# Can I use beginBackgroundTaskWithName for normal app processing

Tags: ios, uiapplication

I have some `NSOperations` that are started regularly in my application.  They should complete even when the the application is put to background. For this, I'm using the `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` method.

Am I supposed to use the `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`/ `endBackgroundTask:` every time I start my task even if the app is not going to background? Or am I supposed the call the begin/end methods only when I detected a `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`?

**Option 1: Use background task every time**

```
/**
 * This method is called regularly from a NSTimer
 */
- (void)processData
{
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier operationBackgroundId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:operationBackgroundId];
        operationBackgroundId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    NSOperation *operation = ...
    [self.queue addOperation:operation];

    operation.completionBlock = ^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:operationBackgroundId];
        operationBackgroundId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    };
}
```

**Option 2: Use background task only when the application is about to go to background**

```
/**
 * This method is called regularly from a NSTimer
 */
- (void)processData
{

    NSOperation *operation =  ...
    [self.queue addOperation:operation];

}


- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier operationBackgroundId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"EnterBackgroundFlushTask" expirationHandler:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:operationBackgroundId];
        operationBackgroundId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // wait for all operations to complete and then


    // let UIApplication know that we are done
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:operationBackgroundId];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: always returns value before expiration handler is called? Otherwise operationBackgroundId is wrong in expiration handler when it is called synchronously. Doc says that it can return also invalid - maybe this is the case when expiration handler is called before returning value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering my own question. From the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html):

> You do not need to wait until your app moves to the background to
> designate background tasks. A more useful design is to call the
> beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler: or
> beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: method before starting a
> task and call the endBackgroundTask: method as soon as you finish. You
> can even follow this pattern while your app is executing in the
> foreground.

Other [Apple API reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler):

> You should call this method at times where leaving a task unfinished might be detrimental to your app’s user experience.
>
> You can call this method at any point in your app’s execution.

Answer (score -2):

**Option2** is correct option.Here is code from Apple document for your reference.

```
 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^{
        // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
        // stopped or ending the task outright.
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

        [self processData];
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```

[Apple developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Comment: But the Apple Documentation says: "You should call this method at times where leaving a task unfinished might be detrimental to your app’s user experience. You can call this method at any point in your app’s execution" https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler

Comment: The problem with Option 2 is that I have to keep track on what has been started and what not. The example code is trivial but the real code is more complex

Comment: Actually, in the same link you posted, Apple say: "You do not need to wait until your app moves to the background to designate background tasks. A more useful design is to call the beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler: or beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: method before starting a task and call the endBackgroundTask: method as soon as you finish. You can even follow this pattern while your app is executing in the foreground."

Comment: I agree with @Jan

Comment: as a follow up, I've been using the Option 1 for a while now in my live apps and it works as expected and didn't have any issues

Comment: Can I have the swift version of this please?